# Not able to display image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using VSCODE to make a blackjack game using HTML, CSS and javascript. I have defined a button that on clicking gives an image(that is stored in computer). Every time I refresh the live server(chrome), it says NOT ALLOWED TO LOAD LOCAL RESOURCE and FAILED TO LOAD RESOURCE: 404 not found. I am new to web development and need help with this project.

```
 let blackjackGame = {
     'you': {'scoreSpan': '#your_blackjack_result', 'div':'#your_box', 'score':0  },
     'dealer': {'scoreSpan': '#dealer_blackjack_result', 'div':'#dealer_box', 'score':0  }

 
 };   
 
 const YOU = blackjackGame['you']
 const DEALER = blackjackGame["dealer"]

 function blackjackHit() {

    var cardImage = document.createElement('img');
    cardImage.src = 'D:\Software Course\JS-Basics\Blackjack\images\Q.png';
    document.querySelector(YOU['div']).appendChild(cardImage);
 }

 document.querySelector("#blackjack_hit_button").addEventListener("click", blackjackHit);
```

Comment: probably need to use the project folder relative path, e.g. if your project is in the folder called Blackjack, set `cardImage.scr = ./image/Q.png`

Comment: cardImage.scr = ./image/Q.png worked for me but i tried with other URL"s also. But when I am using this URL with dot operator it is not coming for the second time. There are no errors or issues too. Please pardon my english

Answer (score 2):

> Every time I refresh the live server(chrome)

The web application is running from a server, even if it's one installed locally or only temporarily hosted within Visual Studio.  As a result, this path won't work:

```
cardImage.src = 'D:\Software Course\JS-Basics\Blackjack\images\Q.png';
```

Because this is a file system path, not a web server URL.  The browser doesn't want to mix those for security reasons.  Instead, provide a URL for the file.  Which *might* be something like:

```
cardImage.src = '/images/Q.png';
```

Finding out the URL is really up to you.  But it'll be some path relative to the URL of the page being viewed in the browser.

Comment: cardImage.src = '/images/Q.png';
I provided this URL, but it gives the error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @SomduttAcharya: That exact URL is just an example based on the information shown in the question.  We can’t know what the real URL is, you’d have to determine that based on where your files are in the web project.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the correct local path from your computer. Then change the backslashs () to forward slashes (/) and add "file:///" before the path, so:

```js
cardImage.src = 'file:///D:/Software Course/JS-Basics/Blackjack/images/Q.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function display_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;

    // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Add image